# Uncaught type error: map function is not working for array variable

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React. I have an array variable but when I call map function it doesn't work. I get "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.state.products.map is not a function"

```
class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            products: []
        };

componentDidMount() {
        fetch(url)
            .then((Response) => {
                this.setState({
                    products: Response.json()
                });
            })
            .catch(err => console.error);
    }
}

 render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="col-lg-12">
                    {this.state.products.map(product1 => (
                        <Button key={product1.id} style={{ color: 'grey', radius: '5px', width: '90px' }}>
                            {product1.title}
                        </Button>
                    ))}
                    <br /><br /><br />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Category;
```

Where am I going wrong? 
Thank you.

Comment: Please share the output of `console.log(Response.json())`

Answer (score 2):

`Response.json()` is a Promise. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json). Assuming you are getting an array from the server you need

```
componentDidMount() {
        fetch(url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((products) => {
                this.setState({
                    products
                });
            })
            .catch(console.error); // because err => console.error is a noop
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, when you're getting response the json response isn't array:

```
products: Response.json()
```

Could you please, check, if it actually array